# Check URL type for redirection in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2. I have the following in my app:

```
  # application_controller.rb
  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url
  end

  def store_referrer_location
    session[:return_to] = request.referrer
  end

  # user_sessions_controller.rb
  def destroy
    store_referrer_location if session[:return_to].blank?
    current_user_session.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Logout successful!"
    redirect_back_or_default root_url
  end
```

If I am at `/places/2/edit`, then I click logout, the `session[:return_to]` would store `/places/2/edit` and attempt to redirect back to `/places/2/edit`, which then redirects to `/login` again.

How can I detect if the `request.url` or `request.referrer` is from the `edit` action, it would just store the `/places/2` only?

I'm thinking of using Regex to check for `edit` word after the ID, but there might be a cleaner way.

Comment: How about using controller.action_name ?

Comment: I think you're solving a problem that doesn't need to be solved here; if you click "logout" on the edit action, then being asked to log in is appropriate. What you might do is store a session variable when you perform a logout redirect that indicates it's such, and if the next request is for a page that requires authentication, you could take some generalized action based on that.

Comment: @ChrisHeald Care to give an example?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to be able to check such a thing on the request.referrer, a regex may be a good option:

```
request.url.gsub(/\/edit$/,'')
```

But if you are actually coming from the edit action, your session[:return_to] should not be blank as you should have done a call to store_location in your edit action.

In such a case, you would not need to check the request.referrer and, as Bigxiang suggested you may change the store_location method to make it store only the show path when you are in edit action

Example

```
# application_controller.rb
def store_location
  session[:return_to] = action_name == 'edit' ? url_for(action:'show') : request.url 
end
```